# How do I get my sandbox paypal account to accept a CSC number with my fake snadbox credit card?

Tags: paypal-sandbox, credit-card

How do I get my sandbox paypal account to accept a CSC number with my fake sandbox credit card number ?

I created a sandbox account with a sandbox credit card number and Expiration date. Paypal did not provide me with a CSC 4 digit number that I need for the Master Card number  and Expiration date it generated for my sandbox account.

I did research and read other questions on stak overflow. From the answers I received I was told that all you need to do is provide a CSC number with 0's or any digit and it should go through and process the transaction for testing.

I also made sure that the credit card was not associated with an existing PayPal account and used faxe credit card numbers with a fake address and name but it did not work.

kind of new to doing this as a developer and running tests.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When testing through the sanbox only the paypal test creditcard numbers will work. The CSV matching those numbers you can make up yourself.

The list of testing numbers is shown here:

http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm

Comment: Yes, the link is dead. For those of us in existence after 2014: if you open the PayPal developer's dashboard, then you will will see "Mock/Credit Card Generator" in the left-hand vertical menu. This will provide valid test credit card numbers.